# Nav Links Went Vertical Instead of Horizonal When I Changed Font?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a test site from scratch to get more comfortable with HTML/CSS and I'm confused. All I did was add a font from Google Fonts and for some reason my nav went vertical rather than horizontal (as it was before) and added back the bullets to the links.

```css
nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="about-me" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="my-work" href="#my-work">My Work</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

I still have "text-align: right" and "list-style-type: none" so I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This what you're after?

```css
nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="about-me" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="my-work" href="#my-work">My Work</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Looks good @Diego! I actually figured it out by doing this: `nav {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}`

`li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

CSS properties needs to be set at `li` element level as all the text are at that level which you want to align left.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

/*******************NavBar******************/
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-height: 16px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #666;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #0080ff;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="NavMenu.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a class="top-nav" id="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="top-nav" id="about-me" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a class="top-nav" id="my-work" href="#my-work">My Work</a></li>
        <li><a class="top-nav" id="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
As per the styles you have used
```

**text-align: right;** contents are aligned in right.

Remove text-align: right; from styles

Comment: That just makes the nav links vertical on the left. I want them horizontal on the right.

Comment: I have added code snippet and details on how to align links horizontally